# WorkManager setting work to 10 years in the future

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Recently, my work manager code has been setting the work to 10 years into the future.

When I run `adb shell dumpsys alarm`:

```
RTC_WAKEUP #0: Alarm{f90d367 type 0 when 1916397034829
```

My code:

```
work.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
    "updateChecks",
    ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
    PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(UpdateWorker::class.java, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .setInitialDelay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .setConstraints(
            Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(false)
                .setRequiresCharging(false)
                .setRequiresDeviceIdle(false)
                .setRequiresStorageNotLow(false)
                .build()
        )
        .build()
)
```

It's been working for months and I have the same kind of code in another application I have working and it's been working fine. But on my Pixel 4 XL running Android 11, it set it to 10 years later. It didn't happen right when I updated but within the last week is when it started. Am I doing something wrong or just going crazy?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. This `Alarm` is only meant to track application force stops. For more information look at https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:work/workmanager/src/main/java/androidx/work/impl/utils/ForceStopRunnable.java

Comment: So is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: There is nothing to fix.

Comment: Is it actually being set at the correct time then? I don't want my update checker to be running once every ten years. It should be running once an hour.

Comment: I think I understand it now...But it still doesn't explain why the worker isn't working anymore.