# PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder is set 40 years in the future

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, android-workmanager, android-media3

I'm trying to set up a PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder that would download some data from our servers every morning at 5am. I have noticed that the worker runs once, and never again, so I'm wondering what is wrong with our configuration, or if there is something that messes up with our configuration. Here is the initial set up I have:

```
        private val uniqueWorkName = MediaDownloadWorker::class.java.simpleName

        private const val WORKER_TAG_OUTPUT = "media_download_worker"
        const val FOREGROUND_NOTIFICATION_ID = 20240212
        const val DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "download_message_notifications"

        /** Enqueues a new worker to download media only if not enqueued already. */
        fun enqueue(context: Context) {
            val manager = WorkManager.getInstance(context)

            val currentDate = Calendar.getInstance()
            val dueDate = Calendar.getInstance()
            // Set Execution around 05:00:00 AM.
            dueDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5)
            dueDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
            dueDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)

            if (dueDate.before(currentDate)) {
                dueDate.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24)
            }
            val timeDiff = dueDate.timeInMillis - currentDate.timeInMillis

            val constraints =
                Constraints.Builder()
                    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.UNMETERED)
                    .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
                    .build()
            val dailyWorkRequest =
                PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<MediaDownloadWorker>(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                    .setConstraints(constraints)
                    .setInitialDelay(timeDiff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .addTag(WORKER_TAG_OUTPUT)
                    .build()

            manager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                "MediaDownloadWorker", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, dailyWorkRequest)
        }
```

The worker itself is an extension of `CoroutineWorker`:

```
class MediaDownloadWorker(private val context: Context, workerParameters: WorkerParameters) :
    CoroutineWorker(context, workerParameters) {
```

And inside the worker I use `androidx.media3.exoplayer.offline.DownloadManager` to schedule a download request for a list of files. I use explicitly the `DownloadManager` since that what we use later to display the videos, and play the voice.

```
val downloadRequest =
            DownloadRequest.Builder(Util.getUtf8Bytes(mediaUrl).toString(), Uri.parse(mediaUrl))
                .setMimeType(mimeType)
                .build()
        downloadManager.addDownload(downloadRequest)
```

To test things out (since it was not updating more than once), I removed the inital delay, and added interval to 15 mins. I created an observer that pulls the worker info, and this is what I see. Before it runs the first time, the `nextScheduleTimeMillis` is when it was supposed to be, a few minutes in the future (or 5 am):

```
Download Worker: WorkInfo{id='03a8deb5-386c-4ac4-a0fd-0be1aa78c8b7', state=ENQUEUED, outputData=Data {}, tags=[worker.MediaDownloadWorker, media_download_worker], progress=Data {}, runAttemptCount=0, generation=0, constraints=Constraints{requiredNetworkType=UNMETERED, requiresCharging=false, requiresDeviceIdle=false, requiresBatteryNotLow=true, requiresStorageNotLow=false, contentTriggerUpdateDelayMillis=-1, contentTriggerMaxDelayMillis=-1, contentUriTriggers=[], }, initialDelayMillis=0, periodicityInfo=PeriodicityInfo{repeatIntervalMillis=900000, flexIntervalMillis=900000}, nextScheduleTimeMillis=1709184279367}, stopReason=-256; next: 1709184279367
```

Once the worker runs, and I observe the info, the `nextScheduleTimeMillis` is ridiculously far in the future, although I very clearly specify the interval. Here is the output. Notice the timestamp being in 2026!!

```
Download Worker: WorkInfo{id='03a8deb5-386c-4ac4-a0fd-0be1aa78c8b7', state=RUNNING, outputData=Data {}, tags=[worker.MediaDownloadWorker, media_download_worker], progress=Data {}, runAttemptCount=1, generation=0, constraints=Constraints{requiredNetworkType=UNMETERED, requiresCharging=false, requiresDeviceIdle=false, requiresBatteryNotLow=true, requiresStorageNotLow=false, contentTriggerUpdateDelayMillis=-1, contentTriggerMaxDelayMillis=-1, contentUriTriggers=[], }, initialDelayMillis=0, periodicityInfo=PeriodicityInfo{repeatIntervalMillis=900000, flexIntervalMillis=900000}, nextScheduleTimeMillis=9223372036854775807}, stopReason=-256; next: 9223372036854775807
```

What could possibly interfere with this? We use a worker in the exactly the same way for updating our Widget, and it works like a charm. Help!

Comment: I've ran into this same exact thing before! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64064304/workmanager-setting-work-to-10-years-in-the-future And even asked a question about it! I don't remember exactly what I did to fix it, so I apologize, but I did get a comment on my post saying that Alarm is supposed to work that way or something.

Comment: Thank you! Doesn't really explain why the worker isn't working, tho :( It would be nice to know how to debug.